# Thunderbird and Google apps

Tags: email, thunderbird, google-workspace, google-contacts

The company I work for uses Google apps for email. I am using Thunderbird with imaps to get my emails. This works well.

I am using the Zindus plugin to sync my contacts. There is one issue. I can get contacts in my contact list, but I cannot get all of the emails of the people in my company to download to Thunderbird or to be able to search for them with in Thunderbird.

When I log into my Google apps email with a browser, I can do a search for people by pressing "To". I need to do this, send the person an email, then use sync in Zindus to download the contact.

Is there a way to configure Thunderbird or a plug in to let me search all the people in my contacts from Thunderbird and without logging into Google apps?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Google Contacts plug-in](https://addons.mozilla.org/af/thunderbird/addon/google-contacts/)?  I haven't used it myself but it looks like it works for some at least.

Also, if you don't update your contacts often you could just download a copy of all your contacts from Google and import them into Thunderbird.  I did this for a user and they seemed to like this solution.  It's not a great one if you use both interfaces and you have to export import back and forth but it does work.  Although you may have to tweak the data in between to maintain the integrity of your contacts.